# Converting the following functions to return promises

Tags: javascript, promise

How would I modify the following function which parses html string so that it returns a deferred promise?

```
function getProductName(html) {
  var temp = document.createElement('div');
  temp.innerHTML = html;
  var name;
  try {
    name = temp.querySelector('h1[itemprop*=\'name\']').textContent.trim();
    $log.debug('Name found: ' + name);
    return name;
  }
  catch(err) {
    return err;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not doing anything asychronous, so if you want to return an already resolved [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), you can do it as such:

```
function getProductNameAsPromise(html) {
    var temp = document.createElement('div');
    temp.innerHTML = html;
    var name;
    try {
        name = temp.querySelector('h1[itemprop*=\'name\']').textContent.trim();
        $log.debug('Name found: ' + name);
        return Promise.resolve(name);
    }
    catch(err) {
        return Promise.reject(err);
    }
}

getProductNameAsPromise(myHtml).then(function(productName) {
    // do something with productName
});
```

See [`Promise.resolve`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve), [`Promise.reject`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/reject)

Comment: @JaromandaX well yes, but that's a flaw in OP's function and nothing to do with promises.

Answer (score 0):

Change getproductName as follows

```
function getProductName(html) {
    var temp = document.createElement('div');
    temp.innerHTML = html;
    var name = temp.querySelector('h1[itemprop*=\'name\']').textContent.trim();
    $log.debug('Name found: ' + name);
    return name;
}
```

and use it like

```
Promise.resolve().then(() => getProductName('')).catch(e => console.error(e));
```

any error will result in rejection, so the catch code will execute

But, as the first answer rightly pointed out, there's nothing asynchronous about the code, so Promises are not really an answer